# Angular 2 modal error on route change

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I am building an angular website where i have two pages. I have a modal in both of the components with the same name. But the problem is that, after I click on a link and click on modal, both the modal pops up coz its of same name. Shouldn't it be independent modals because its in different pages or am i doing something wrong?Please help.

This is how i am assigning routes to tabs

```
 <a [routerLink]="'/home/'+x.linkValue" routerLinkActive="activeroute" id="tab">
```

where x is taken from backend

Let me know if any code is required.

Comment: Modal is a component with a view? how are linked the two pages? are they siblings or parent - child ?

Comment: modal is not a seperate component.each page is different wit two different route links.Each page has its on modal in the template.Pages are not connected.Just that two modals have same name.

Comment: what do you call modal? a modal div?

Comment: yes..thats defined in htm inside div element.When a user clicks on the button,it opens

Comment: You probably use a shared service which serves both components